# One game layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a match game layout in android.
I'm having problem with making my layout compitable to all screen resolutions.
What I want, is an image icon of the home team on the left, a strechable home team image name, home team score text, seperator, away team score text, a strechable away team image name, an image icon of the away team on the right.
The score should be in the middle. I just can't get it right. before this try, I've tried to divide the main layout to 3 layouts: home team layout, score layout and away layout - with no success of getting the expected result.

Can someone please help ?

Here is my piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/GamesBGColor" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeTeamIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/holonlogo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeTeamText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
            android:layout_gravity="center"            
            android:src="@drawable/holontext"
            android:layout_width="115dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeTeamScore"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="123"
            android:textColor = "@color/purple"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"            
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seperator"
            android:layout_width="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/awayTeamScore"
            android:layout_width="25dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="122"
            android:textColor = "@color/red"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"            
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dip" />

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/awayTeamText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"            
            android:src="@drawable/jerusalemtext"
            android:layout_width="115dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"/>

         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/awayTeamIcon"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/jerusalemlogo" />

      </LinearLayout>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your layouts to work on different resolution screens your should be sizing them using `dip` as the unit.  For example:

```
android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
```

`dip` stands for Device Independent Pixel and using these in your layout means that Android will automatically scale your layout depending on which display the device running your application has.

You can read about these in the [*Supporting Multiple Screens* page in the Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#screen-independence).  This document also has some other options for handling different displays but I think using `dip` is probably the easiest.

Comment: as you can see I did used dip. My problem is that it doesn't strech to a full horizontal row. I have some space left in the right on screens larger than 4in. If i'm increasing the dip of the home team name for instance, the icon of the away team is not fitting 2.7in screen and gets out of the screen.

Comment: In that case you can use Droiddraw to see the physical structure.It'll give you some idea what can be exact value of dip which you should use to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to use the designer but still can't figure out how I'm filling a row according to what I need. In a lower resolution I'm getting an overflow in the right side, and in a higher I haven't set enough "dip"'s for the text..